# How kml files work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, kml

Can I use run time coordinates in a kml file? If so, how? Please give me a simple example how to fetch value for that? I'm waiting for answer.

Comment: Can you explain this question better?  What do you mean by "run time coordinates"?  At any rate, Google's docs are pretty good, and they have excellent examples if you don't like to read through the text.

Comment: "I'm waiting for answer...." seriously?

Answer (score 0):

i think kml file is a type of xml file. you can parse the file as a xml file

for more details check this link [kml doc by google](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html)